# Link Azure Website to Azure DNS for easy Custom Domains?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Right now to create a custom domain you have to setup a cname for verification, and then you have to setup your real record, and then you can finally after that go and add it to the site.

I'm doing this scripted with C# and that's tedious considering that we're hosting our DNS with Azure. I would have thought that I could have added an a record to Azure and then add it directly to the website automatically but I can't figure out how to do this.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can skip the whole Cname creation stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase a custom domain through Azure Web Apps? 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

If you did, then everything should get automatically setup properly.

If you didn't, then you'll need to do the work to set it all up yourself.

Comment: No, but the domain is setup in azure DNS and name servers all hooked up and it works fine. It should just allow any azure DNS a record to hook up. Heck should allow a drop down.